# How to determine the type of flow using the XML metadata file of the flow?

Tags: visual-workflow, metadata-api, xml

How do I determine whether a flow is a Screen Flow, Schedule-Triggered Flow or Record-Triggered Flow etc. from the metadata?

Here is a flow of type Screen Flow:

rule.flow

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Flow xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
    <apiVersion>57.0</apiVersion>
    <environments>Default</environments>
    <interviewLabel>createRecordPracticeRule {!$Flow.CurrentDateTime}</interviewLabel>
    <label>createRecordPracticeFlow</label>
    <processMetadataValues>
        <name>BuilderType</name>
        <value>
            <stringValue>LightningFlowBuilder</stringValue>
        </value>
    </processMetadataValues>
    <processMetadataValues>
        <name>CanvasMode</name>
        <value>
            <stringValue>AUTO_LAYOUT_CANVAS</stringValue>
        </value>
    </processMetadataValues>
    <processMetadataValues>
        <name>OriginBuilderType</name>
        <value>
            <stringValue>LightningFlowBuilder</stringValue>
        </value>
    </processMetadataValues>
    <processType>Flow</processType>
    <recordCreates>
        <name>createRecordElement</name>
        <label>createRecordElement</label>
        <locationX>176</locationX>
        <locationY>158</locationY>
        <connector>
            <targetReference>updateRecordElement</targetReference>
        </connector>
        <object>Account</object>
        <storeOutputAutomatically>true</storeOutputAutomatically>
    </recordCreates>
    <recordUpdates>
        <name>updateRecordElement</name>
        <label>updateRecordElement</label>
        <locationX>176</locationX>
        <locationY>278</locationY>
        <inputReference>recordVariable</inputReference>
    </recordUpdates>
    <start>
        <locationX>50</locationX>
        <locationY>0</locationY>
        <connector>
            <targetReference>createRecordElement</targetReference>
        </connector>
    </start>
    <status>Draft</status>
    <variables>
        <name>practiceVariable</name>
        <dataType>String</dataType>
        <isCollection>false</isCollection>
        <isInput>false</isInput>
        <isOutput>false</isOutput>
        <value>
            <stringValue></stringValue>
        </value>
    </variables>
    <variables>
        <name>recordVariable</name>
        <dataType>SObject</dataType>
        <isCollection>false</isCollection>
        <isInput>false</isInput>
        <isOutput>false</isOutput>
        <objectType>Account</objectType>
    </variables>
</Flow>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can see the type of the Flow from `processType` attribute.

```
<processType>Flow</processType>
```

Per documentation we see when processType is flow it is a flow that contains a screen, hence screen flow.

> Flow—A flow that requires user interaction because it contains one or
> more screens or local actions, choices, or dynamic choices. In the UI
> and Salesforce Help, it’s a screen flow. Screen flows can be launched
> from the UI, such as with a flow action, Lightning page, or web tab.

For the scheduled flow and the others do not require user interaction we also need to check `triggerType` attribute to learn further about the flow type.

Here is the relevant part from the documentation:

```
The type of the flow, as determined by the active version, or the latest version, if there’s no active version. Valid values are:
ActionCadenceAutolaunchedFlow—A flow executed when a user completes a cadence step. This value is available in API version 56.0 and later.
ActionCadenceStepFlow—A screen flow used as a cadence step. This value is available in API version 56.0 and later.
Appointments—A flow for Lightning Scheduler. This value is available in API version 44.0 and later.
AutoLaunchedFlow—A flow that doesn’t require user interaction.
CheckoutFlow—A flow used in Lightning B2B Commerce to create a checkout in a store. This value is available in API version 48.0 and later.
ContactRequestFlow—A flow that lets customers request that customer support gets back to them. This flow is used to create contact request records. This value is available in API version 45.0 and later.
CustomerLifecycle—A Salesforce Surveys flow that lets you associate survey questions with different stages in customer lifecycles. This value is available in API version 49.0 and later and only when the Customer Lifecycle Designer license is enabled.
CustomEvent—A process that is invoked when it receives a platform event message. In the UI, it’s an event process. This value is available in API version 41.0 and later.
EvaluationFlow—A flow for evaluating custom entry and exit conditions in an orchestration. Uses the isOrchestrationConditionMet output variable and discards values from any other output variables. Available in API version 54.0 and later.
FieldServiceMobile—A flow for the Field Service mobile app. This value is available in API version 39.0 and later.
FieldServiceWeb—A flow for embedded Appointment Booking. Its UI label is Field Service Embedded Flow. This value is available in API version 41.0 and later.
Flow—A flow that requires user interaction because it contains one or more screens or local actions, choices, or dynamic choices. In the UI and Salesforce Help, it’s a screen flow. Screen flows can be launched from the UI, such as with a flow action, Lightning page, or web tab.
FSCLending—A flow for Financial Services Cloud Mortgage. This value is available in API version 46.0 and later.
IndividualObjectLinkingFlow—A flow that associates individuals with interactions such as voice calls, messaging sessions, or case-related emails. This value is available in API version 58.0 and later.
InvocableProcess—A process that can be invoked by another process or the Invocable Actions resource in REST API. This value is available in API version 38.0 and later.
LoginFlow—A flow for login. Available in API version 51.0 and later.
LoyaltyManagementFlow—A flow for the Loyalty Management app and can be invoked by loyalty program processes. This value is available in API version 54.0 and later.
Orchestrator—An orchestration that organizes flows into groups of steps contained in a series of stages. Available in API version 53.0 and later.
RoutingFlow—A flow for Salesforce Omni-Channel routing and other business logic. This value is available in API version 52.0 and later.
Survey—A flow for Salesforce Surveys. From the UI, this type of flow is created in Survey Builder. This value is available in API version 42.0 and later.
SurveyEnrich—A Salesforce Surveys flow that uses the Survey Data Mapper. From the UI, this type of flow is created in the Survey Builder and requires an associated survey flow type. This value is available in API version 49.0 or later and only when the Customer Lifecycle Designer license is enabled.
Workflow—A process that is invoked when a record is created or edited. In the UI and Salesforce Help, it’s a record change process.
Across flow versions, you can change the type only from Flow to AutoLaunchedFlow or vice versa. Before you change the flow type, make sure that the flow contains only elements, resources, and functionality that the new flow type supports.

These values are reserved for future or Salesforce internal use.

ActionCadenceFlow
ActionPlan
AppProcess
CartAsyncFlow
DigitalForm
Journey
JourneyBuilderIntegration
LoginFlow
ManagedContentFlow
OrchestrationFlow
RecommendationStrategy
SalesEntryExperienceFlow
TransactionSecurityFlow
UserProvisioningFlow
This field is available in API version 31.0 and later.
```

triggerType:

> Specifies what causes the flow to run. If you exclude this field, the
> flow has no trigger and starts only when a user or app launches the
> flow. Possible values are: EventDrivenJourney—Reserved for internal
> use. PlatformEvent—The flow starts when a platform event message is
> received. This value is available in API version 49.0 and later.
> RecordAfterSave—The flow starts after a record is saved. This value is
> available in API version 49.0 and later. RecordBeforeSave—Creating
> and/or updating a record triggers an autolaunched flow to make more
> updates to that record before it’s saved to the database. This value
> is available in API version 48.0 and later.
> RecordBeforeDelete—Deleting a record triggers an autolaunched flow
> before the record is deleted from the database. This value is
> available in API version 50.0 and later. Scheduled—The flow starts at
> the scheduled time. This value is available in API version 47.0 and
> later. ScheduledJourney— The journey starts only at the scheduled time
> and frequency. This value is available in API version 49.0 and later.
> Available only when processType is AutoLaunchedFlow. This field is
> available in API version 47.0 and later.

Documentation on Flow attributes [here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_meta.meta/api_meta/meta_visual_workflow.htm)